# How to remove default space when using flex-box?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  }
#parent-container {
    display: flex;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    /*flex-direction: column;*/
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    /*justify-content:space-between;*/
}

#rd-box{
   width:100%;
   background-color:rgba(176,39,39,1);
   height: 25%;
}

#sky-box{
    height: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(0,255,255,1);
}

#yllw-box{
    height: 25%;
    background-color: rgba(255,242,0,1);
}

#grn-box{
    height: 37.5%;
    background-color: rgba(0,255,0,1);
}

#bl-box{
    height: 37.5%;
    background-color: rgba(0,33,87,1);
}

#item:nth-child(3){
    order: 2;
}



/*---common  styles----*/

.wd-half{
    width: 50% ! important;
}

.item{
    margin:  0px ! important;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pro.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="parent-container">
            <div id="rd-box" class="item">  </div>
            <div id="sky-box" class="item wd-half"> </div> 
            <div id="grn-box" class="item wd-half"> </div>
            <div id="yllw-box" class="item wd-half"></div>                
            
            <div id="bl-box" class="item wd-half">  </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm new with flex box and that is why I asking this question.In the above code there is a default white space is generated between the green and blue part.how can I avoid that?.How can i fix this?.Is the structure need to be reconstructed?

I'm trying to achieve this

[image]

Comment: You specified the height as 25% respectively 32.5%. So isn't the result exactly what you have specified? As far as I know flexbox works either row-wise or column-wise, never both. Maybe you're looking for something like Masonry?

Comment: 32.5%+32.5%=65% and not 75%. you aware of it right?

Comment: @connexo i'm added an image

Comment: @jafar i don't think that is the cause of this problem

Comment: You will have to put the left and the right side each in a column wrapper container, and apply your flexbox css to those. Then make the columns themselves flexboxes with flex-direction: row. I'm not sure that works though, you need to try. Given the current markup what you want is not achievable by CSS means as far as I know.

Comment: @conexxo that is it

Comment: Connexo is right. This is not achievable with simple flexbox css. if you want i can help this without flexbox

Comment: @jafar oh..sorry ,i need the answer with flexbox

Comment: On testing, you can remove several styles `#item:nth-child`, `item`, `parent-container`, and you can move both the `display: flex;` and `flex-wrap: wrap;` inside the `html, body` style. The move the elements from inside the `<div id="parent-container">` outside to the `<body>` level, and get rid of the `<div id="parent-container">` div.  Doesn't resolve the problem, but simplifies it a bit.

Comment: I did some more digging for you.  This tutorial walks through how to use `flex` for a masonry structure. https://medium.com/@_jh3y/how-to-pure-css-masonry-layouts-a8ede07ba31a#.2w0u9m2di    and to see their final result in action (code is a bit messy as it contains flip css, among other things, but i cleaned it up and made a codepen from it) >  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XNpgLL

Comment: Take a look at the solution by jafarbtech below.  In my opinion, this is solid. I added a (very) minor change to it so it fills with no overflow, but it looks great, and seems to be the cleanest you will get this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution (By Using a new `div.sub-container`):-**

Flexbox grows in one direction either row or column. as your question deals with more than one direction (first div-row wise achievable. and others are column wise achievable) i have added one more div(`div.sub-container`) with flexbox and **changed the height** according to the `div.sub-container`.

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
  }
#parent-container {
    display: flex;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    /*justify-content:space-between;
    flex-direction: column;*/
}

#rd-box{
   width:100%;
   background-color:rgba(176,39,39,1);
   height: 25%;
}

#sky-box{
    height: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(0,255,255,1);
}

#yllw-box{
    height: 25%;
    background-color: rgba(255,242,0,1);
}

#grn-box{
    height: 37.5%;
    background-color: rgba(0,255,0,1);
}

#bl-box{
    height: 37.5%;
    background-color: rgba(0,33,87,1);
}

/*---common  styles----*/

.wd-half{
    width: 50% ! important;
}

.item{
    margin:  0px ! important;
}
.sub-container{
    height: 75%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
/*newly calculated height with respect to sub-container*/
.sub-container #sky-box{
    height: 66.6666666667%;
}
.sub-container #yllw-box{
    height: 33.3333333333%;
}
.sub-container #grn-box{
    height: 50%;
}
.sub-container #bl-box{
    height: 50%;
}
```

```html
    <body>
        <div id="parent-container">
            <div id="rd-box" class="item">  </div>
            <div class="sub-container">
            <div id="sky-box" class="item wd-half"> </div>  
            <div id="yllw-box" class="item wd-half"></div>    
            <div id="grn-box" class="item wd-half"> </div>   
            
            <div id="bl-box" class="item wd-half">  </div>
            
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

**Partial Solution (Without flexbox):-**

I am not going to use flexbox as flexbox grows in one direction either row or column. as your question deals with more than one direction (first div-row wise achievable. and others are column wise achievable) i am not sure this will work with flexbox. So i m giving you solution without flexbox

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
  }
#parent-container {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#rd-box{
   width:100%;
   background-color:rgba(176,39,39,1);
   height: 25%;
}

#sky-box{
    height: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(0,255,255,1);
}

#yllw-box{
    height: 25%;
    background-color: rgba(255,242,0,1);
    clear: left;
}

#grn-box{
    height: 37.5%;
    background-color: rgba(0,255,0,1);
}

#bl-box{
    height: 37.5%;
    background-color: rgba(0,33,87,1);
}

.item:nth-child(3){/*
    order: 2;*/
}



/*---common  styles----*/

.wd-half{
    width: 50% ! important;
    float:left;
}

.item{
    margin:  0px ! important;
}
.sub-container{
  height:75%;
  width:50%;
  float:right;
  clear: right;
}
.sub-container div#grn-box,.sub-container div#bl-box{
  width:100% !important;
  height:50%;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
    <body>
        <div id="parent-container">
            <div id="rd-box" class="item">  </div>
            <div id="sky-box" class="item wd-half"> </div>  
            <div class="sub-container">
            <div id="grn-box" class="item wd-half"> </div>   
            
            <div id="bl-box" class="item wd-half">  </div>
            
            </div>
            <div id="yllw-box" class="item wd-half"></div>    
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: I added the final touch to your solution(s) and upvoted you -  great job.  The edit was adding `overflow: hidden;` and `margin: 0px;`  to your `html, body` css.  Good clean code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change mark up for this .

I could achieve by doing as below.check this snippet

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.parentcontainer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.second {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#rd-box {
  background-color: rgba(176, 39, 39, 1);
  height: 25%;
}
#sky-box {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 1);
}
#grn-box {
  width: 50%;
  height: 37.5%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 1);
}
#yllw-box {
  width: 50%;
  height: 25%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 242, 0, 1);
}
#bl-box {
  width: 50%;
  height: 37.5%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 33, 87, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="parentcontainer">
  <div id="rd-box"></div>

  <div class="second">
    <div id="sky-box" class="wd-half"></div>
    <div id="yllw-box"></div>
    <div id="grn-box">

    </div>

    <div id="bl-box"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Take the red `div id="rd-box"` out of the container and uncomment the  `flex-direction: column;` rule. Like this:

```
    <div id="rd-box" class="item"></div>
    <div id="parent-container">
        <div id="sky-box" class="item wd-half"></div> 
        <div id="grn-box" class="item wd-half"></div>
        <div id="yllw-box" class="item wd-half"></div>                
        <div id="bl-box" class="item wd-half"></div>
    </div>
```

And change the CSS rules

```
    #parent-container {
        display: flex;
        width:100%;
        height: 100%;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
```

Then you should review the maths on your %, as mentioned on some comments they don't match the 100%